# Access value from string in list in Python?

Tags: python, list

So, I am attempting to create a list of responses for each command for a game I am creating. In previous languages that I have used I would be able to just do the following:

```
myList[] = ["1" : "2", "3" : "4"]
```

This would allow me to, for example, access the string "2" if I just typed in:

```
myList["1"]
```

but this does not seem to work in python. Also, as a side note, I would like to know what it's called when you create a list like "myList". (Layered Lists?)

Thanks in advance,
Twin802

EDIT: My Current code, the one that doesn't work, is:

```
AI = [
"Hello" : "Hi",
"Goodbye" : "Bye"]
```

Comment: Please read the python tutorial before trying to code. It will save you time. Trust me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're thinking of a dictionary which maps a key to a value. Try this instead:

```
AI = {"Hello" : "Hi", "Goodbye" : "Bye"}
```

Comment: Thank you this worked. But I can't choose this as my answer til 10 minutes from now.

Comment: That's fine. Do what you need to do.

Comment: Could you mark as answer Twin802?

Comment: Yeah, Sorry I had to go somewhere. Here you go.

Answer (score 1):

you need to be using a dict

it is represented as such

```
dict = {key : value, key : value}
```

so for you you would need to do something like this.

```
In [1]: AI = { "Hello" : "Hi", "Goodbye" : "Bye" }

In [2]: print(AI["Hello"])

Out[3]: 'Hi'
```

keep in mind you can also add `.key` and `.value` on to get the key of that index or the value of that index.

there is more info about dictionaries [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects)